# See check status in GitHub Pull request Checks tab

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have installed Azure Pipelines Marketplace app on GitHub: https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines

During the installation process, I selected the repository and ended up with the configuration flow to create a new `.yml` file.

BUT - I already have a rather advanced build definition set up in Azure DevOps (configured 2-3 years ago) and it won't let me export it to YAML.

So as a result, when a Pull Request is opended the Checks tab in GitHub shows the Azure Pipeline check, but just says it is queued and it never updates:
[image]

Status checks are still reported back to the PR, using the old way - the top one is build status, reported back automatically from Azure DevOps PR trigger:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove completely Azure Pipelines application:

- go to your GitHub installation settings : https://github.com/settings/installations or https://github.com/[organization]/[project]/settings/installations
- open configuration for Azure Pipelines
- Uninstall Azure Pipelines application

Then reinstall https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines application.